# Monitoring resque with monit with RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, resque, monit

I previously had Monit monitoring resque with the following Monit script

```
check process resque_worker_production_QUEUE
  with pidfile /var/tmp/resque_production.pid
  start program = "/usr/bin/env HOME=/home/eg RACK_ENV=production PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/ruby/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:$PATH /bin/sh -l -c 'cd /apps/eg/production/current; nohup bundle exec rake environment resque:work RAILS_ENV=production QUEUE=mailer VERBOSE=1 PIDFILE=/var/tmp/resque_production.pid & >> log/resque_worker_production_QUEUE.log 2>&1'" as uid eg and gid eg
  stop program = "/bin/sh -c 'cd /apps/eg/production/current && kill -9 $(cat
```

Then I changed some things around, most notably removing the system-wide rvm install and I'm assuming a ruby install at /usr/local/ruby/bin . Around this time monit could no longer start resque. Maybe the cause was something else but I'm thinking it was these uninstalls that caused the breakage.

So I looked throught the script and noticed that /usr/local/ruby/bin doesn't exist, so I tried changing it to what I think it should point to now that the ruby in my rvm is the only one around /home/eg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin

But that didn't work. So I google some more and found this suggestion which also didn't work:

```
check process resque_worker_production_QUEUE
  with pidfile /var/tmp/resque_production.pid
  start program = "/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /apps/eg/production/current; nohup bundle exec rake environment resque:work RAILS_ENV=production QUEUE=mailer VERBOSE=1 PIDFILE=/var/tmp/resque_production.pid & >> log/resque_worker_production_QUEUE.log 2>&1'" as uid eg and gid eg
```

All I get in the log is:

```
[UTC Oct  5 03:06:38] error    : 'resque_worker_production_QUEUE' process is not running
[UTC Oct  5 03:06:38] info     : 'resque_worker_production_QUEUE' trying to restart
[UTC Oct  5 03:06:38] info     : 'resque_worker_production_QUEUE' start: /bin/bash
[UTC Oct  5 03:07:08] error    : 'resque_worker_production_QUEUE' failed to start
```

So I'm not sure how to debug this further. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's in your monit log? You should check there to see what the exact issue is.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure, do you have RVM loading script in bash files?
Something like:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

For me it works with:

```
check process <%= pid_name %>
  with pidfile <%= pid %>
  start program = "/bin/bash -c -l -i 'cd <%= current_path %> && NEWRELIC_ENABLE=false HOME=/home/<%= resque_user %> RAILS_ENV=<%= rails_env %> QUEUE=<%= queue %> PIDFILE=<%= pid %> BACKGROUND=yes VERBOSE=1 <%= fetch(:bundle_cmd, "bundle") %> exec rake resque:work >> <%= shared_path %>/log/resque.log 2>&1'" as uid <%= resque_user %> and gid <%= resque_group %> with timeout 180 seconds
```

I see difference in **-i flag**, not sure if it's required, and in **order** of **env variables**

Have you **checked resque logs**? (log/resque_worker_production_QUEUE.log as I see)

Another thing to try is to run this command after ssh'ing to server as **root** (or another monit user), ***sudo su*** won't be enough as you'll already have rvm loaded, so better try from scratch. It can reveal some errors.

Also check out this page http://rvm.io/integration/cron for tips